# PHPUnit Mock Function Call

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I have the following function within an object that I wish to test

```
public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
{
    $resourceOwner = $this->getAuthClient()->fetchUserFromToken($credentials);

    // ... Code to create user if non-existent, update values, etc.
    // ... Basically the code I want to test is here

    return $user;
}
```

The `getAuthClient()` call returns a `Client` object with the available function of `fetchUserFromToken`

How can I, in a PHPUnit test, mock the `fetchUserFromToken` to just return a `ResourceOwner` object? Because the actual function does a lot of authentication mechanisms and is out of the scope of this test case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a php library called [Runkit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php), but that is not the approach I want to peruse. It feels hacky and overkill for the problem at hand.

The `getAuthClient()` function is defined as follows

```
private function getAuthClient() {
   return $this->clients->getClient('auth');
}
```

With `$this->clients` being defined by the constructor

```
public function __construct(ClientRepo $clients) {
    $this->clients = $clients;
}
```

So, I mocked the `ClientRepo` and exposed the `getClient()` method to return a Mock of the `AuthClient` (regardless of input) so that I can control the return of `fetchUserFromToken()` call.

```
public function testGetUser() {
    $client = $this->createMock(WebdevClient::class);
    $client->expects($this->any())
        ->method('fetchUserFromToken')
        ->will($this->returnCallback(function()
        {
            // TARGET CODE
        }));

    $clients = $this->createMock(ClientRegistry::class);
    $clients->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getClient')
        ->will($this->returnCallback(function() use ($client)
        {
            return $client;
        }));

    $object = new TargetObject($clients);

    $result = $object->getUser(...);

    // ... Assertions to follow
}
```